# How to reproduce Rabbitmq AlreadyClosed Exception locally

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have the following code to publish message to RabbitMQ. I am getting AlreadyClosed exception sometimes in production. I would like to reproduce the same issue in my local machine(i.e DEV server). Any idea on how to reproduce it?

```
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props = new AMQP.BasicProperties().builder();
props = props.deliveryMode(2).headers(headers);
rabbitChannel.getChannel().basicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey,
                                props.build(), rabbitMessage.serialize());
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the connection explicitly while you are debugging the code , then you will be able to reproduce it in local.

Comment: You can do that in the Management Web UI. Select the connection and click Force Close

Answer (score 1):

You can close connections manually via the Management Web UI.

If you want to create an integration test that tests behaviour of your application when the connection dies then you can close connections via the HTTP API programmatically. I run my integration tests against a local instance of RabbitMQ an so simply request all the open connections via the API and then call DELETE on each one.